# Usar "from x import y" em python reduz o tamanho da aplicação?

Tags: python

Se eu fizer um impor na forma "from X import Y" ao invés de "import Y" estou economizando no tamanho da aplicação final ou não faz diferença?

Digamos que dentro de Y tenha milhares de funções mas eu desejo usar apenas X em meu código, ao executar a aplicação com o "from/import" estou garantido que menos código terá que ser processado ou isso irá apenas organizar minha aplicação?

Comment: Não faz diferença, é apenas uma referência que você está usando. Como se cada import fosse uma variável, grossamente falando

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não faz diferença nenhuma no tamanho final da aplicação.

Quando se manda ler algo de um módulo em Python, mesmo que seja só uma variável de um módulo, ele é executado (como qualquer arquivo .py) - as funções, classes e variáveis definidas no módulo são criadas e ficam disponíveis a partir dali.

A única diferença de fazer `from X import Y` é que no módulo onde você fez a importação só vai ser criada a variável `Y` que vai fazer referência à mesma variável `Y` que está no módulo `X`. Da mesma forma, se você faz `import X`, só é criada a variável `X`, que faz referência ao módulo inteiro.

Se X tem milhares de funções e variáveis, todos ficam em memória e disponíveis para serem imediatamente utilizáveis - outros comandos de `import` do mesmo modo nunca vão ler o módulo `X` do disco de novo:
depois do primeiro `import`, o módulo X fica disponível em `sys.modules['X']` - e outros `import ... from X`  vão pegar as referências direto dali.

Por outro lado, dado o tamanho da memória de PCs convencionais e mesmo a disponibilizada em servidores virtuais hoje em dia, dificilmente *código*  vai deixar o programa mais pesado - bytecode Python, que é o que é lido quando importamos um módulo tem mais ou menos o mesmo tamanho que o código fonte - talvez uns 30% maior - e, sempre temos que ter em mente que toda a Bíblia cristã por exemplo, quando contada como texto, ocupa apenas 3MB: ou seja, um programa que tivesse tanto código quanto a bíblia tem texto ocuparia uns 4MB de memória só para ser importado - contra PC's típicamente com 8000MB de memória, ou mesmo servidores virtuais com 512MB.

O tempo de inicialização de um módulo pode pesar um pouco - para algo tão grande podendo chegar a alguns segundos se o arquivo .pyc não existir ainda. Mas se é o caso de existir uma biblioteca com milhares de items que pode pesar no executável final, cabe ao autor da biblioteca separa-la em subpacotes, que tenham que ser explicitamente importados.

Comment: Bem completa a resposta, respondeu minha dúvida. Não sabia a respeito do sys.modules também.

Answer (score -1):

A principal vantagem de importar partes especificas com o **from import** é não ter a repetição do modulo no código e consequentemente um código mais "limpo" ex.:

Usando o **import X**:

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)
d2 = datetime.date(2010, 1, 31)
d3 = datetime.date(2008, 5, 17)
d4 = datetime.date(1992, 2, 18)
d5 = datetime.date(1899, 6, 22)
```

Usando o **from X import Y**

```
from datetime import date

d1 = date(2000, 1, 1)
d2 = date(2010, 1, 31)
d3 = date(2008, 5, 17)
d4 = date(1992, 2, 18)
d5 = date(1899, 6, 22)
```